# Amazon ELB - how to identify connection draining facility?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

[This article says that I should be able to find "Connection Draining" somewhere in the Load Balancer details pane.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-connection-draining-remove-instances-from-service-with-care/)

However,  it isn't there. Is this something expected? I raised a case with Amazon, but doesn't look like anyone is reading. Does anyone know if I have missed anything ?

Answer (score 2):

Connection Draining = [Deregistration Delay](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#deregistration-delay) for NLB and ALB.  Set it under `Target Groups > Attributes`.